# DDD - Why do we need factories?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, domain-driven-design, factory

**Short version**

Why would we ever need factories (being injected in the application layer) in DDD if no aggregates will ever emerge out of thin air and doing so would cause at least an error in the modeling of the business ?

**Long version**

There is a popular DDD example which is the e-commerce application consisting of the following aggregates and entities (over simplified)

[image]

Modeled as

```java
class Customer {
  private CustomerId id;
  // related business rules and processes
}

class Order{
  private OrderId id;
  private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
  // related business rules and processes
}

class OrderLine{
  private OrderLineId id;
  private int quantity;
  private ProductId product;
  // related business rules and processes
}
class Product{} 
// etc...
```

And it's well established that the creation of the order is done through a factory, usually like:

```java
Order order = orderFactory.createNewOrder(customer);
```

However I'm arguing that this model is not very clear since I assume the original (made up) requirement is

> Customers can place orders.

So doesn't it make more sense to delegate the creation of the order to the `Customer` aggregate and have the code more verbose ? i.e:

```java
Order order = customer.placeOrder(...);
// Pass the data needed for the creation of the object, or even the factory service if the creation is complex
```

In my opinion, expanding this view would result in that the actors of the system would be aggregates most of the time and they will contain all the *invoking* of the use cases (which has the side-effect that the application layer being very thin as well)

Does this second approach violate DDD ? An aggregate being responsible for the creation of another aggregate doesn't feel right but produces better code that -in my opinion- matches the domain better.

Comment: With `customer.placeOrder(...)` you'd be giving this responsibility to the `Customer` class. Is that what your application needs? At the end of the day, it depends on _your_ requirement. But to me it sounds like that'd be giving too much responsibility to the `Customer` class.

Comment: It's indeed alot of responsibility on the `Customer` since all of the use-cases will be invoked by it (and other actor classes). However, if we integrate the concept of bounded contexts and raise proper domain events these methods should get thinner and thinner IMO.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this second approach violate DDD

No.  The patterns described by Evans in the Domain Driven Design book should be understood as "useful ideas that recur" rather than "these patterns are mandatory".

And you will find support in the literature for the idea that, when we are modeling the creation of aggregates, we should be using the domain language, not factories.  For example: [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](https://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/comment-page-2/) (Udi Dahan, 2009).

That said.... when Evans describes the FACTORY pattern in his book, he does so in the context of life cycle management, not modeling.  In other words, factories are cousins to repositories and aggregates, not domain entities and value objects.

> Shift the responsibility for creating instances of complex objects and AGGREGATES to a separate object, which may itself have no responsibility in the domain model but is still a part of the domain design.

In other words, we might still want to use `Customer::placeOrder` in our domain model, but to have that method delegate the object assembly to a dedicated factory.

---

Of course, object creation is not the only place that we use the factory pattern; it can also appear in object reconstitution.  A common REPOSITORY pattern is to fetch information from the durable data store, and then pass that information to a FACTORY to arrange that information into the appropriate shape - aka the graph of objects that make up the AGGREGATE.

---

I understand the factory pattern as an example of [information hiding](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/), the factory limits the blast radius when we decide to change how a fixed set of information is assembled into an aggregate.

Comment: Thanks, so expanding this would mean that it's actually ok for the `Customer` aggregate to have a method that creates another aggregate - `Order` in this case - ?